# I want to insert multiple items in items table in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create an invoice. I have form for insert invoice details. I have two tables for insert invoice details and invoice items table. I want to insert data in both tables respectively.

I want to insert date, address, invoice from, bill to and so on in invoice table and items in the invoice item table.

When I submit form I got below response in console.

I want to insert red underline details in invoice items table.

[image]

I have write below code for my operation:

```
exports.postAddInvoice = (req, res, next) => {
  const party_name = req.body.party_name;
  const order_date = req.body.order_date;
  const address = req.body.address;
  const sub_total = req.body.sub_total;
  const bill_from = req.body.invoice_from;
  const bill_to = req.body.bill_to;

  const prods = req.body.product;
  const qty = req.body.qty;
  const prices = req.body.price;
  const total = req.body.total;
  
  req.user.createOrder_invoice({
    order_date: order_date,
    order_receiver_name: party_name,
    order_receiver_address:address,
    bill_from:bill_from,
    bill_to:bill_to,
    order_total_amount: sub_total,
  })
  .then(result => {
    res.redirect('/');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  res.render('admin/add-invoice', {
      pageTitle: 'Add Invoice',
      path:'/add-invoice',
      activeInvoice: true
  });
};
```

Invoice details are inserted in invoice table.

I used sequelize, mysql database for this app.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?  What does PHP have to do with this question?

Comment: you have a bug, you are calling `res.render()` at the end as well as the `then/catch` in the result of `req.user.createOrder_invoice()`. Consider using `async/await` to make this async code more intuitive. You should also include the `Model.create()` that you are using to do the insert.